# Find in source control --> Status option in Visual studio 2010 not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, tfs-power-tools

I have both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 connecting to TFS 2008.

In Visual studio 2008 i can see the if some particular person has checked out any file by the option

<kbd>Find in source control</kbd> > <kbd>Status</kbd>

But when I am trying to see same thing via 2010 I can't find it.

When I try to install the Visual Studio 2010 Power Tools for Team foundation Server (Dec '11), I get the following error message:

> ### TFS Power Tools
>
> ---
>
> Setup detected that a previous version of this product installed for the following users. These per-user ("Just Me") installations must be removed before this version of the Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools can be installed on the machine ("Everyone").
>
> <kbd>Close</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

This option in available through the [Visual Studio 2010 Power tools for Team Foundation Server](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f). You can install multiple versions of the Power Tools side-by-side, but you can only have one version of the Windows Explorer extensions installed. I usually opt for the latest version for that feature.

Uninstall the older version of the power tools and then install them (oldest to newest). For each older version deselect the "Windows Explorer Integration" and the "Powershell cmd-lets", I tend to only install the latest version of those.

You can find the older versions here:

- 2005: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation Server Power Tools - September 2007 release](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10443)
- 2008: [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server Power Tools - October 2008 Release](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15836)
- 2010: [Team Foundation Server Power Tools December 2011](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)
- 2012: [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)
- 2013: [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)

When installing make sure you always select to install for "All Users" that way you should be able to install all of these side-by-side as long as the corresponding version of Team Explorer is installed as well.

If you're connecting to TFS 2008, then you only need the TFS Best Practice Analyzer from the 2008 power tools and you should use the Visual Studio 2008 Developer Command Prompt for commands that do Team Project Creation or interact with Sharepoint/ReportServer. This is exactly the same as when you're editing Work Item Definitions using witadmin, you can't edit the 2008 work items definitions with the 2010 version of widadmin.

From experience, the following commands/features are server version specific:

- Tfpt addprojectreports
- Tfpt addprojectportal
- Tfpt createteamproject
- Work Item Editor
- Best Practice Analyzer

And these should work with any TFS version as long as the corresponding version of Team Explorer supports said TFS version.

- Explorer Integration
- Check-in policy pack
- Source Control Explorer extensions
- Team explorer extensions
- Work Item templates
- Powershell commandlets
- Other tfpt commands

A [complete overview of the tools that will/will not work depending on your TFS and Visual Studio version can be found on my blog](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/Install-Team-Foundation-Server-Power-Tools-side-by-side.html).

You should install the Windows Explorer extensions and Powershell cmd-lets from the highest version of the Power Tools you intend to install. The latest version has seen the most development and will have fewer bugs.

The 2010 tools won't break your TFS 2008 installation.

Comment: Thanks I have found it a bit earlier but not sure whether i should install it or not.Now i will check it.

Comment: got the error 
---------------------------
TFS Power Tools
---------------------------
Setup detected that a previous version of this product installed for
 the following users.  These per-user ("Just Me") installations must be
 removed before this version of the Microsoft Team Foundation
 Server 2008 Power Tools can be installed on the machine ("Everyone").

Don't know what to do so that when working with VS2008 and TFS will work as well as i can work with VS2010 and TFS 2008 with the option of find in source control by status

Comment: It looks like the 2008 version is installed "for the current user only" and the 2010 one wants to install "for all users on this machine". Remove the 2008 version and install it "for all users on this machine".

Comment: Will it not break any thing if i uninstall 2008 version. I am doubtful as we have TFS 2008 edition on server and we are installing TFS 2010 power tool on client while we doesn't have TFS 2010

Comment: Infact i were not able to find "Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools" in Program and features

Comment: thanks jessehouwing. 
Didn't find it either :( [May need help from my network administrator to login with old users's credential]
I don't worry about the addproject report but will check createteamproject is needed from my machine or not.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may need to open and activate the Source Control Explorer to see this menu command. This is the case in VS 2015.